# Order of convergence of a product of two convergent sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n$ be a sequence that converges to $A$ with order of $n^\alpha$, that is $a_n = A + \mathcal{O}(n^\alpha)$ and $b_n$ is another sequence that converges to B with order of $n^\beta$; i.e. $b_n = B + \mathcal{O}(n^\beta)$. What is the order of convergence of $a_n \cdot b_n$?

My intuition tells me that:

$$ a_nb_n = AB + \mathcal{O}(n^{\min(\alpha,\beta)})$$

but could not formulate the proof. I used the trick:

$$|a_nb_n - a_nB + a_nB - AB| \leq |a_n||b_n-B| + |B| |a_n-A| \leq K n^{\alpha}n^{\beta}+ Bn^{\alpha}$$

Note sure how to go on.

Comment: Note $\alpha, \beta<0$ so your intuition is misleading you. Also there is a mistake in the last inequality given; how did you bound $a_n$?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I derived the bound based on the definition of big O notation: if $a_n$ has order $\mathcal{O}(n^\alpha)$, then $|a_n| \leq Kn^{\alpha}$. Isn't that correct? Also, I am not sure how you know that $\alpha, \beta <0$. But if that is the case, then the order of the covergence of $a_nb_n$ converges with $n^{\max(\alpha,\beta)}$?

Comment: to indicate convergence you must have $\alpha, beta$ negative. When they are negative $A$ is dominant in the bound for $a_n$

Comment: I see. Do you know exactly what would be the order of convergence of the product then? At least I will have something to aim for in my proof :)